# how to append a line alignment with its previous line in linux?

Tags: linux, sed, find, xml

I have many xml files. There is a line end with `</autoReferenceLines>`. The line may have different leading spaces in different files. I want to add a new line below that line with the same leading spaces in all files.

I was able to add the new line, but I don't know how to make the new line has the same alignment as its previous line.

what I have now is this:

```
find ${location} -type f -name "*.xml" -path "**/adult/**" -exec sed -i '/<\/autoReferenceLines>/a <ztv>0<\/ztv>' {} +
```

**EDIT:**

I notice there are tools for xml editing, such as `xmlstarlet`. But in my this case, it will be the best to just use bash command. I don't have permission to install it.

Is there a way to count the leading space for a specific line? for example to count the leading space for line with `</autoReferenceLines>`

**EDIT2:**

input:

```
  <Parameter> 
    <autoTransfer>Nowhere</autoTransfer>
    <toFilm>0</toFilm>
    <autoReferenceLines>0</autoReferenceLines>
  </Parameter>
```

Bug in different files, the indent is not the same. So the leading spaces for each line are different.

expected output:

```
  </Parameter>
    <autoTransfer>Nowhere</autoTransfer>
    <toFilm>0</toFilm>
    <autoReferenceLines>0</autoReferenceLines>
    <ztv>0</ztv>
  </Parameter>
```

Comment: sed is the wrong tool for xml (or json) editing. There are XML tools, that can do better. Sorry I don`t know there names.

Comment: `xmlstarlet`, `xml`

Comment: `xmlstarlet` is as much a "`bash` command" as `sed` is.

Comment: Indentation is not important between tagl in XML files. Just run your XML document through an XML formatter such as `xmltidy`.  `xmlstarlet` and `xmltidy` can be, like most Unix tools, installed in a user's home directory. You don't need special permissions to install and use these tools.

Comment: @Kusalananda In some circumstances, you just don't allow to make any unnecessary changes on the target environment, such as product computer. you can install/update your software on the system, but the hardware/OS/running environment may belong to other groups.

Comment: @peterboston Well, you will have to weigh a robust solution requiring a single extra tool to be installed against a solution that depends on the non-essential layout of the document staying the same.

Comment: If you proved me a solution and then down vote my question, I will thank you and accept your vote. If you feel it is difficulty too, please leave it alone. Why hate questions you cannot answer by down vote it? If you think I didn't research enough then please give the link you found. I've done lot of research. I have reasons to stick with bash cmd solutions because I am not allow to change the running environment, and we have lots of update bash scripts there already.  The down vote will not kill me. I just cannot understand why you are not patient/kind enough to be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Gnu sed you can do this. Im using your find command and modified the sed portion in it.

```
$ find ${location} -type f -name "*.xml" -path "*/adult/*" -exec sed -i -e '/<\/autoReferenceLines>/!b' -e 'h;s/\S.*/<ztv>0<\/ztv>/;H;g' {} +
```

Or, spread out by means of escaped newlines but still considered one line:

```
$ find ${location} -type f \
   -name "*.xml" -path "*/adult/*" \
   -exec sed -i \
    -e '/<\/autoReferenceLines>/!b' \   
    -e 'h;s/\S.*/<ztv>0<\/ztv>/;H;g' \
   {} +;
```

**Working:**

The `find` that you wrote nicely selects the required files that need to be edited by `sed`.

The sed command looks at lines where the auto reference string is present. It stores a copy: `h` before we begin a surgery on it. Then starting from the first non whitespace `\S` to the end of line we erase it all. So now we're left with leading whitespace(if any). While we're at it we stick the desired string ztv also. So now we have same number of leading whitespace plus the desired string.

Next we append this just created string to the original stored line `H` and get `g` it into the pattern space.

The `-i` option when used with multiple files to gnu sed, implies the `-s` so we don't explicitly give it.

Comment: Wow! it works! could you please explain your command?

Comment: @peterboston Edited my post to add a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This command should do what you want :

```
find ${location} -type f -name "*.xml" -path "**/adult/**" -exec grep -q '</autoReferenceLines>' {} \; -exec perl -i"*" -ne 'print; print "$1<ztv>0</ztv>\n" if (m[^(\s*).*</autoReferenceLines>])' {} \;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but it doesn't work, nothing changed

Comment: Can you paste a sample input and expected output ?

Comment: please see the Edit2

Comment: I didn't realize the line contains beginning tag as well. I updated my solution.
My solution modified only those files that contains the tag.

Comment: your solution works now! Nice work.